# how i can resize a image in imageView after zooming?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Goal : After zoom . resize a image in scrollView?

I have a imageView inside a scrollView. After zoom a image when i place another image in imageView by imagePicker it already zoomed. I wants when i pick another image in imageView it fit to screen. I try few code

```
        CGSize scrollSize = scroll.frame.size;
        [scroll setContentSize:scrollSize];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

but it not works for me.

Thanks

first time image [image]

after zoomed image is [image]

when i again pick the image by imagePicker  image is [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial has all code that you need

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

Answer (score 0):

Use following codeinto scroll view delegate method

> [scrNxt setZoomScale:1 animated:NO];

Example like below.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    if(scrollView==self.scr){
                    [scrNxt setZoomScale:1 animated:NO];

}
```

this may solve your problem